# How to select a button value from a form in Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am attempting to automate class registration.

The relevant section of HTML for the page displays as such:

```
<form id="SearchClasses" name="selectedStatusForm" action="/more/SearchClasses.action" method="post" class="checkboxButtonForm">
<input type="checkbox" name="enrollmentStatuses" value="E" checked="checked" id="enrolledCheckBox"/><input type="hidden" id="__checkbox_enrolledCheckBox" name="__checkbox_enrollmentStatuses" value="E" />

<script type="text/javascript">

var enrolledCheckBox = function()
{
   var updateHiddenFields = function()
   {
       hiddenCheckbox.checked = button.get("checked");
   }

   var params = { label: "Enrolled", name : "enrollmentStatuses", type : "checkbox", value : "E" };
   var onclick = function(){  
      updateHiddenFields();
             YAHOO.mis.student.Topics.onEnrollmentFilterChangedEnrolledValue.fire();
     };
   params.onclick = {};
   params.onclick.fn = onclick;
   params.onclick.obj = null;
   params.onclick.scope = false;

   var button = new YAHOO.widget.Button("enrolledCheckBox", params );
   var originalCheckedStatus = button.get("checked"); 
   button.set("checked", true);
   var hiddenCheckbox = button.createHiddenFields();
   button.set("checked", originalCheckedStatus);
   updateHiddenFields();

   return button;
}();
</script>
```

There are also buttons under the same form with other values, but I am trying to select value "E". Given that each registration needs to be personalized to each student, the button is seen this way when logged into the page:

```
<tr id = "StudentCartList_classSectionListRow_0_header" class = "classRow">
<td class = "classSelection">
<input type = "hidden" name= "enrollmentRequestItems[0].classNumber" value="2000">
<input type = "hidden" name= "enrollmentRequestItems[0].waitList" class="waitListHidden" value= "false">
<div class = "enrollmentMenu Div">
<span id = "yui-gen26" class= "yui-button yui-menu-button enrollmentButton">
<span class = "first-child">
<button type= "button" id= "yui-gen26-button"> E </button>
</span>
</span>
<div id ="yui-gen27" class = "yui-module yui-overlay yuimenu yui-button-menu yui-menu-button-menu yui-overlay-hidden" style= "z-index: 1; position: absolute; visibility: hidden;">
</div>
</td>
<td id ="classNumber_2000" class= "classSection" onclick = "YAHOO.mis.student.Topics.showClassDetailPanel.fire({classNumber : '2072', termCode : '0955', hideAddToCartButton : 'false'})">
</td>
```

I don't know how to select the button. I've tried

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.checkboxButtonForm[value= 'E']").click();
```

I've also tried

```
selector = driver.find_element_by_name("enrollmentStatuses");
selector.click();
```

In the first case, the element was not found. In the second case, an "ElementNotInteractableException" was thrown.

I also thought that I might have to use the Javascript Executor, but in order to do that I'd have to select my "E" value from the button element first.

How should I proceed to successfully click the button? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try following options:

Option 1:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'E')]")).click();
```

Option 2:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='button' and contains(text(),'E')]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code -

```
# Do these imports
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
action = ActionChains(driver)

driver.get("Your URL")

Button_Click = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'enrollmentStatuses')))
action.move_to_element(Button_Click).click().perform()
```

Let me know if it works.